# Trying to get login error messages/validation to work on login form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, authentication

I have a login system for a member/admin site. The login is working perfectly, but I want to verify the user and give error messages if it's not the correct user or password. So far, with what I have, it will not give any error messages although I'm not getting any errors either.

```
function error_message(){ $error = '';
$loginName = isset($_REQUEST['loginName']) ? $_REQUEST['loginName'] : "";
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : ""; 
{$results = connect($loginName);
    $loginName === $results['email'];
    $passwords = password_verify($password,$results['password']);
    if(!$results) {$error = 'Username not found'; echo $error; header     ('Location: home.php');} //if no records returned, set error to no username
  else //if found     {if ((isset($password)) !== (isset($passwords)))  //check password, if matched log him in
     { $error = 'Password is wrong'; echo $error; header('Location:     home.php');} //if not matched then set error message
   }
 }
   if(isset($error)) {echo $error; }//if there is an error print it, this      can be anywhere in the page
}
```

This is my connection and how it is logging in:

```
function connect($loginName) {
    global $db;
 $query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email     ='$loginName'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
}
```

Login:

```
 function login($loginName, $password) {
    $results = connect($loginName);

    if(!$results) {
        header('Location: /tire/admin/home.php?err=1');
    }

    if ($loginName === $results['email'] && password_verify($password,$results['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['loginName'] = $loginName;

        if ($results['level'] === 'a') { // 1 == Administrator
            $_SESSION['level'] = 'Administrator';
            header('Location: /tire/admin/home.php');
         } elseif ($results['level'] === 'm') { // 1 == Member
            $_SESSION['level'] = 'Member';
         header('Location: /tire/member/home.php');
            exit;
     }
     }

     header('Location: /tire/admin/home.php');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's some nasty code we have here. Let's get started:

Let's first take a look in the `connect` function:

- Gets the row where the email matches the `loginName` provided.
- Return the array with the desired row.

That's correct.

Now let's take a look to the `login` function:

- Retrieves the row where the email matches `loginName`.
- If there is no row (email does not match any user), redirects to `home.php` of ¿ADMIN? with the variable `$err = 1`.
- Recheck the email (what for?) and verify the password.

  - If password is correct, it checks permissions and redirects to the correspondent `home.php`.
  - Notice that if there is no matches for a permission, it redirects you to admin `home.php`.
  - Notice that if the password is incorrect, you do nothing.

I will improve this code:

```
function login($loginName, $password) {
    $results = connect($loginName);

    if(!$results) {
        header('Location: /tire/error.php?code=1');
    }

    if (password_verify($password,$results['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['loginName'] = $loginName;

        if ($results['level'] === 'a') { // 1 == Administrator
            $_SESSION['level'] = 'Administrator';
            header('Location: /tire/admin/home.php');
         } elseif ($results['level'] === 'm') { // 1 == Member
            $_SESSION['level'] = 'Member';
         header('Location: /tire/member/home.php');
            exit;
         }
    } else {
         header('Location: /tire/error.php?code=2');
    }
}
```

And then in `error.php` (or whatever place you would like to show the errors, it's just an example):

```
switch($_GET['code']){
    case 1:
        $error = "Email invalid";
        break;

    case 2:
        $error = "Password invalid";
        break;
}

print $error
```

That being said, I will strongly recommend you to read about exceptions and implement the logic based on that. It's far more clean than the code above, but I didn't want to change your code so drastically.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I ended up using a jquery plugin that works. This was not working. sorry.